# wireless bridge while keeping a subnet

Tags: wireless-bridge, bridge-router

Hopefully this question hasn't been asked. I couldn't find anyone asking my particular question.

In my house I have a wireless network. I would like to connect 2 wired computer to the network (which is easy enough). But what I am having issues figuring out is if I can have the 2 computers talk to each other via the wired connection since they are part of a cluster. I cannot connect the cluster nodes to the main router via a wired connection.

I know I could do this if I buy a bridge and then plug a router into it, which I then connect both of my devices to. However I haven't been able to find anything that can server as both a bridge and a router in one.  The idea is I do not want my cluster nodes to have to go all the way out over the wifi to talk to each other.

Or is the bridge smart enough to simply route the traffic between the two computers without going out to the main router via Wi-Fi?

I know I will have no issue with the computers communicating with each other. What I don't want is the 2 cluster nodes to have to use wifi to talk to each other.  They are Hadoop/Spark cluster nodes and I want them to talk to each other via the gigabit ethernet and not have to go back to the wireless router.  I only want them to go to the wireless portion of the network to get to the internet.

Comment: Why would you need the device to do any routing? It would only be connected to one network. However, it would need to support *true* bridging, that is, WDS. So the big question is -- does your existing router support WDS? Can you just connect both wired devices to your existing router? If not, what's the issue preventing you from doing this?

Comment: Updated the question.  Running wires to the existing router is not an option.  I simply want the 2 cluster nodes to talk to each other via ethernet and the internet via wireless.

Comment: Then the big question is -- does your existing router support WDS?

Comment: Only those that really love the raw pain of pulling their own hair out use WDS

Comment: how did my question get a -1?  I thought it was a pretty legitimate question.  I have a wireless network.  I have a cluster of computers that I would like to connect to said wireless network, but I want the cluster to communicate internally via ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the devices are on the same IP network, the traffic will not go to a router; routers connect networks. If the devices are on different IP networks, then, and only then, would you need to go through a router.

Hosts on a layer-2 network, like ethernet, token ring, Wi-Fi, etc., will connect directly to each other via MAC address. Hosts connecting to a host on a different layer-3 network will need to go through a router (gateway). The host can tell to which MAC address (host or gateway) it should send the layer-2 frame by comparing the source and destination layer-3 addresses using the address mask. If they match, it sends the layer-2 frames directly to the host on the local network, otherwise it sends the frame to the configured gateway.

A switch is really just a multiport bridge. A Wi-Fi bridge with multiple wired ports is a transparent ethernet bridge (switch) and a translation bridge for ethernet and Wi-Fi. If the bridge only has 1 wired port, you can connect it to a small ethernet switch for the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks,  I think this was the answer I was looking for.   So if I use a multport bridge or just take a router and flip it into bridge mode,  it will route trafic between the computer connected to it without going back to the router via wifi?

Comment: Yes, if there is no reason to translate the ethernet to Wi-Fi, it won't. The hosts will only send something to the router when sending something off the local network as configured by IP address and mask, and then they will target whichever gateway is configured in them. That will involve crossing the Wi-Fi to the WAP which will then get to the router and sent out the WAN..

Comment: any suggestion on a piece of hardware I can purchase to do this?  I would guess any gigabit router which can be put into bridge mode.

Comment: Product recommendations are explicitly off-topic. Most of the manufacturers have wireless bridges which will work, and they are less expensive than a router. I have a 4-port wireless bridge doing something similar to what you want, but it is older so it doesn't support the latest Wi-Fi or 1 Gb, and I have thought of replacing it with one that does, but it does everything I need for now. I sometimes search to see what's available, and there are plenty on the market.

Answer (score 1):

Nanostation M2 works as a Bridge or router/access point. I set one up as an access point/router and it is perfect.

Comment: while a good solution, it is only 2 ports with no room for expansion.  I've actually had a nanostation before.  Awesome technology.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question right, you just need a router with a LAN switch built in. Or you could get a switch that you can connect to your router and connect the PC's to the switch.

A bridge looks at the destination of the frame before sending, if the destination address is not on the other side of the bridge it will not transmit the data across. This helps break up one large broadcast domain into 2 by using one bridge device.

A switch has multiple ports in which each port is its own collision domain, a switch will determine the source and destination of the incoming data and switch it to the port it needs to go to.

Comment: right I am looking for some type of wireless bridge/switch.   Have a look at my edits, it should make more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Many wireless routers have a "client" mode, where the wireless component acts like a regular wireless client. There should be an option to bridge the wireless with the Ethernet ports as well. This way, it won't do any routing, and it will just act like a regular switch, which will achieve what you want.

Comment: yes essentially turning the wireless router into a bridge.  The question is, is it smart enough to route requests between the clients connected via ethernet to it solo without sending the data to the wireless router to which it is connected.

Comment: Yes- that's how a switch works (it's not called routing though).